# Payment APIs in android

Tags: android

Is there any google payment APIs for android like we are having "paypal" ?
And
I want to implement credit card payment process in my android application. There is a form in my application. User will enter his card information and on submission the service will verify and accept or reject the card. I have no idea if there is any API or a tutorial available in android. Please help me if someone knows how to do that.

Comment: take a look at this: https://www.x.com/community/ppx/xspaces/mobile/mep

Comment: I guess what you are looking for is Android Market's InApp Billing http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/index.html

Comment: I am having one activity which ask user to fill all required credit card information and when press "buy" , transaction will gets done with using that credit card info . How can i do it ?

Comment: You should try this tutorial [1] http://www.androiddom.com/2011/02/android-shopping-cart-tutorial.html [2] http://www.androiddom.com/2011/06/android-shopping-cart-tutorial-part-2.html

Comment: But There is no any payment APIs in that demo. And I want it.So what is next ?

Comment: Is there any google payment APIs ?

Comment: there is no such API from Google. but at least a lot of users have a PayPal account and don't have to type in their credit card number.

https://www.x.com/community/ppx/xspaces/mobile/mep

Comment: without paypal , is it possible to pay in android ?

Comment: As per my knowledge Not Possible without paypal. Sample application of google [In-app Billing Overview](http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/billing_overview.html)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3816/discussion-between-nandlal-virani-and-uttam)

Answer (score 1):

You might consider the Temboo Android SDK, which provides normalized access to a large number of APIs. It includes modules for interacting with both Stripe (https://www.temboo.com/library/Library/Stripe/) and PayPal (https://www.temboo.com/library/Library/PayPal/ProcessDirectPayment/)

The SDK is an open download, which you can grab at https://www.temboo.com/download although you'll need a (free) Temboo account to do anything with it.

(Full disclosure: I work at Temboo)